# JQuery function to increase the font size everywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a click function that increases the font size of every piece of text (`p`, `a`, `span`, `h1`, etc.). I don't want to have to use a selector like

```
var allText = $('.page-container a, .page-container p, .page-container h1, .page-container h2, ...');
```

because I want this to be general and maintainable. Can my wish be granted?

Comment: If your child elements have their `font-size` declared in relative units (`%`, `em`, etc) then you can do this by increasing the `font-size` of the `<body>` element from which those other elements should base their own.

Comment: If you use a relative font size across the app (em's for example), then yes it's pretty easy. You just need to increase the font-size on the root element (typically in the body) and everything else will adjust accordingly.

Comment: `$('body').css('font-size','desiredNewSizeInPixelsOrPercentageOrWhateverLikeEM');` ? if you really want to apply it to every single text, then why not applying it from the document directly? http://jsfiddle.net/vdj5xebn/

Comment: using a base font size for body, and em else where is the safest approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given simplified HTML such as the following (since you didn't provide any, in your question):

```
<button id="up">+</button><button id="down">-</button>
<h1>Heading text</h1>
<div>
    <p>A div, with</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Various elements</li>
    </ul>
     <h2>And another heading</h2>

    <aside>At this point, I'm sure that you get the point</aside>
    <blockquote>But if you don't, then I'm sure it can be explained</blockquote>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* This is more or less irrelevant, it's just to show
   that the <body> element has an explicit font-size,
   in pixels (but em would work also) */
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
/* and all other elements have relative font-sizes,
   basing their own font-size upon the inherited
   font-size from their ancestors: */
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
div {
    font-size: 1em;
}
ul {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
aside {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
blockquote {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-left: 2px solid #f90;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

The following jQuery will work:

```
// binds a simple click event-handler:
$('button').on('click', function(){
    // caching the clicked element:
    var clicked = this;
    // selecting the <body> element,
    // using the css() method to set the 'font-size'
    // via the anonymous function:
    $('body').css('font-size', function (i,size) {
        // i: the index of the current element in the collection
        // size: the current value of the current element

        // using parseInt to get a number in base-ten,
        // adding either 2 (if the clicked element was #up)
        // or -2 (if the clicked element was not #up):
        // appending 'px' to the number to make it a valid
        // css unit:
        return parseInt(size,10) + (clicked.id === 'up' ? 2 : -2) + 'px';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kvu3zt4j/).

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Now, this is a solution, Good job, well deserved +1! Also, great use of the .css callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*').css('font-size', '15px');
```

Might do the trick.

Comment: this will can set size of all elements, but it will disrupt the proportion/ratio of font sizes between elements.

Comment: It might; if he's using really small font-sizes for heading (`<h1>`, `<h2>`...) elements.

Comment: In some cases as suggested by David, it will decrease font-size, not increase it

Answer (score 0):

this solution enlarges the text proportionally.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.big').on('click', function() {
        $('*').each(function() {
            var fontsize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
            console.log(fontsize);
            var newFontsize = (fontsize * 1.1) + 'px';
            console.log(newFontsize)
            $(this).css('font-size', newFontsize);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="big">englarge<a/>

<p>askdjfhasjdhf</p>
<a>lkajsdlfkjasdf</a>
<h1>askjdflasf</h1>
a;sldkfalskdfsdf
```

Comment: You don't need `each()`, just use `css()`: `$('*').css('font-size', function(i, currentSize) { return (parseInt(currentSize, 10) + 2) + 'px'; });` for example; jQuery iterates over everything internally anyway, you may as well use that.